transform.forward doesn't point forward after rotation
I have a person GameObject who the player can control with the arrow keys. When the player presses left or right, I rotate the character using Transform.Rotate.
However, I discovered a discrepancy that I can't explain when trying to move the character forward.

If I set the velocity on the Gameobject's Rigidbody component (by pressing up), then the character moves in the direction they are facing.
If I however use Tranform.Translate in the transform.forward direction (by pressing W), then the character doesn't move in the direction they're facing. They instead move in the direction that they would have been facing if they'd had that rotation applied twice. So for instance, if I hold left until they've rotated 45 degrees and then press W, the character will translate as if I'd rotated them 90 degrees and then pressed Up.

void Start()
{
    m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    m_Speed = 1.0f;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        m_Rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * m_Speed;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * m_Speed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Time.deltaTime * m_Speed * 50, Space.Self);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * Time.deltaTime * m_Speed * 50, Space.Self);
    }
}

I've printed the transform.forward direction and it always seems to point in the direction the character is facing. So then why does Transform.Translate in the transform.forward direction not move the character in the direction they're facing?
Possible configuration options that may be affecting things:

The character has a convex MeshCollider
The character's Rigidbody is not kinematic and is constrained to have its X and Z rotation frozen.


The confusion is about local and world coordinates. Let's break it down:
transform.Translate(m_Speed * Time.deltaTime * transform.forward)

If you don't specify a Space, Transform.Translate() moves your object in local coordinates. Now, transform.foward grabs the local forward vector but returns it in world coordinates. Therefore, you have two options:

In local coords:
transform.Translate(m_Speed * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.forward);


In world coords:
transform.Translate(m_Speed * Time.deltaTime * transform.forward, Space.World);



Btw: Reordering the multiplication factors can play a role in terms of computational efficiency since scalar multiplication is faster than vector muliplication

Thanks for the answer and for the bonus tip about computational efficiency.
